# PDO could not find driver, even with extension=pdo_pgsql enabled

Tags: php, symfony, pdo, xampp

I've upgraded PHP5.6 to PHP7 on my XAMPP on Windows 10 to run my symfony project. It works fine when updated schema in the console, but it showed "could not find driver" in webpage when it tried to connect to DB.

I changed the extension directory to 
extension_dir = "C:/xampp/php/ext"

And I've already enabled the extensions as below,

```
extension=bz2
extension=curl
extension=fileinfo
extension=gd2
extension=gettext
;extension=gmp
extension=intl
;extension=imap
;extension=interbase
;extension=ldap
extension=mbstring
extension=exif      ; Must be after mbstring as it depends on it
extension=mysqli
;extension=oci8_12c  ; Use with Oracle Database 12c Instant Client
;extension=odbc
extension=openssl
;extension=pdo_firebird
extension=pdo_mysql
;extension=pdo_oci
extension=pdo_odbc
extension=pdo_pgsql
extension=pdo_sqlite
extension=pgsql
;extension=shmop
```

But it gave me DriverException: 'An exception occured in driver: could not find driver', object(PDOException))

Can anyone help me with this?

Comment: Did you checked phpinfo() through PHP ?

Comment: Have you restart xampp?

Comment: my advice is, to actually run phpinfo from both cli and via web and check whether the php.ini that is loaded is actually the same. it's quite common to have two ini files, one for cli and one for web.